# Test are not executed during build time

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I use this Maven configuration in order to execute TestNG collection of tests:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central Repository</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>google-api-services</id>
            <url>http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version> <!-- There is a bug into the latest version 7.4.0. Wait for next stable version to be released before upgrade. -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Selenium dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.52.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.21.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.22</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I compile the project or run `clean test` tests are not executed. Do you know how I can configure the tests to be executed?

EDIT. Example for test:

```
package org.mobile.login;

import org.automation.utils.BrowserDriver;
import org.automation.utils.jaxb.Environment;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.utils.LoginProcess;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.automation.utils.Constants.*;

public class ReloadPageTest extends LoginProcess {

    private Environment env;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        env = setupEnvironment();
    }

    @Tag("description")
    @Order(1)
    @Test(testName = "52333 Mobile Web - Reload a page to refresh it", groups = { "multiple_runs" })
    @Timeout(value = 80, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void Mobile_Web_Reload_a_page_to_refresh_it_52333() throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver = new BrowserDriver().initDriver();

        // Navigate to Test Environment
        driver.get(env.getConfiguration().getUrl());
        .....
}
```

Comment: Are your [test sources in `src/test/java` and the classes named `*Test.java`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Configuring_TestNG)?

Comment: Tests are always executed by default, unless you add `--skip-tests` to the command line. Make sure you are using the right annotations from the right packages as well as what Gerold said.

Comment: Which framework do you use? TestNG? Or JUnit Jupiter?

Comment: I use TestNG as you can see from the dependencies.

Comment: I see dependencies for testng as well as for JUnit Jupiter (junit-jupiter-engine) which is the problem here... you have to decide which one you use...

Comment: I want to use TestNG with some JUnit functionalities. How I can fix this proejct?

Comment: No, please decide! ;) ..and please also provide (at least) a test.

Comment: First why using TestNG? What specific feature do you use of TestNG which JUnit Jupiter doesn't have?

Comment: I use TestNG because I can group tests.

Comment: I added basic example for test.

Comment: This can be done via Junit Jupiter via Tag annotation furthermore you can use nested classes to categorize tests as well. Apart from that your test example show the usage of TestNG annotation and Junit Jupiter annotation within a single test which will not really work...and I suppose that's exactly the reason why your tests are not correctly running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.2 instead of 3.0.0-M5:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
```

When changed, the test get executed.

Comment: Can verify that this fixed a recent project of mine as well.